# Changing the favicon in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to change the favicon in my wordpress blog. I am still not able to do so. I am using the Magazine Basic theme.

The website I am working on is www.quantgreeks.com. When I type, http://www.quantgreeks.com/favicon.ico, I still get the HostGator symbol.

I have tried this and none working:

1. http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/how-do-i-change-my-favicon-1
2. http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Favicon
3. http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-a-favicon-to-your-wordpress-blog/

Added this two lines to header.php:

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.quantgreeks.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.quantgreeks.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Not of any use..

Need some guidance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the correct steps if you followed any one from those sources.

I checked your site and I believe the favicon is the letter 'J'? See screenshot:

[image]

The issue you're having is probably from an old cache in your browser. Try clearing your browser cache and try again.